# How to achieve fast video transmission between esp32 cam to a pc?

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, drone.io, arduino-esp32

To make an autonomous drone and help it fly from one place to another without any human intervention, I plan to send data using two ESP32s and receive those data using my PC. I won't use the onboard navigation system inside the drone. I need suggestions regarding the signal-receiving unit (using wifi i will send the data), which will feed information directly to my PC. Kindly give me information on the best way to receive signals from ESP32 to PC, in the shortest amount of time and with a reasonable budget.

We were thinking about NodeMCU, but we aren't going to use it. Moreover, I am in the initial phase and have just started researching this. Also, I am pretty new to this, so any suggestions will help me to discover and also help me get what I want.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure if this question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Did you already read the the Help Center page on what questions are on-topic here? If so, can you explain to my why this is on topic? (since I'm not sure). If not, please read it and consider whether your question is on-topic here. If you're not sure where to ask this question, you can ask on meta.stackexchange.com using the \[site-recommendation\] tag.

Comment: Why are there TWO ESP-32s? Is it a relay? How can WiFi have enough range for a drone? What size are your images in pixels? Colour or greyscale? What frame rate do you want/need?